# Import node module trough ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, npm, ecmascript-6

I've want to import the [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/) library with NPM. 
Although it's not just for PhotoSwipe, but general for NPM modules I guess.

If installed trough `npm i photoswipe -S` as mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/photoswipe. 
I didn't run any grunt tasks, because I saw the dist map isn't empty.

I'm only using vanilla JS so my code is as following:

```
import 'photoswipe';

const galleryElem = document.querySelector('.gallery');

if (typeof(galleryElem) !== 'undefined' && galleryElem !== null) {
    const imgArray = [];
    const galleryImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__image');

    // Fill imgArray trough looping.. (skipped for this post)

    const gallery = new window.PhotoSwipe(galleryElem, false, imgArray);
    gallery.init();
}
```

But unfortunately I get the error:
`TypeError: window.PhotoSwipe is not a constructor`

Importing as `import * as PhotoSwipe from 'photoswipe';` results in the same error.

I've also tried importing the libraries as found in the following code https://gist.github.com/di5abled/d8d84af3be5e1bf12507

But then I get the error: `Cannot find module`..

All my JS files are bundled in a file called app.js loaded in the footer.

So I'm not sure how to import the library and use it correctly. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried the basic `import photoswipe from 'photoswipe'`?

Comment: try `import { 'PhotoSwipe' } from '../node_modules/photoswipe'` .use `../` to jump directories accordingly.

Comment: Did you launch node with --harmmony ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The harmony flag isn't necessary since I'll run babel tasks. The simple import from @LeoNapoleon was required.. Can you explain me why this works and `import 'photoswipe'` doesn't?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does import Module from 'module' import when no default export is defined and why is it different from import \* as Module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542427/what-does-import-module-from-module-import-when-no-default-export-is-defined-a)